# Send associate array with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have associated array.

```
var arr =   Array();
arr['a']    =   123;
arr['b']    =   234;
arr['c']    =   345;
arr['d']    =   456;
arr['e']    =   567;
```

i want to send this array with jquery ajax. This is not in my form so when i will click on submit button then it should come in my form so that i can post associate array data

```
<form id="sendProposalForm" action="<?php echo frontpath(FILENAME_AJAXFILE);?>" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="sendRequestProcess" />      
<input type="hidden" name="durationHidden" id="durationHidden" value="0"  />
<input type="hidden" name="priceSenstivityHidden" id="priceSenstivityHidden" value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="responseRateHidden" id="responseRateHidden" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="addTagsHidden" id="addTagsHidden" value=""   />
<input type="hidden" name="addAttachmentHidden" id="addAttachmentHidden" value=""   />
<input type="text" name="attachmentOrignalNameHidden" id="attachmentOrignalNameHidden" value="" />
```

```
$.ajax({url    :    "<?php echo frontpath(FILENAME_AJAXFILE);?>",
    type   :    "post",
    data   :    $('#sendProposalForm').serialize(),
    success:function(res) {                 

    }
  });
```

Comment: merge the form data with your associated array before your send the ajax request?

Comment: How to merge? i am trying to merge but not gettin any success yet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
var arr = Array();
arr['a'] = 123;
arr['b'] = 234;
arr['c'] = 345;
arr['d'] = 456;
arr['e'] = 567;

var obj = $.extend({}, arr); /* convert your array to an object */

$.ajax({url: "<?php echo frontpath(FILENAME_AJAXFILE);?>",
    type: "post",
    data: $('#sendProposalForm').serializeArray() + '&' + $.param(obj), /* merge your form with the new obj (your array) */
    success: function (res) {
        alert('SUCCESS!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious time

Answer (score 1):

So what is wrong? Can't you just add that array to Ajax request too?

```
data: {
     formData: $('#sendProposalForm').serialize(),
     assocArray: '<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>'
}
```

Comment: The `assocArray` is already a JavaScript object, so can add it without the `php` code, like: `assocArray: arr`.